# Install LWP Perl module on debian + Others

Tags: linux, debian, perl

I'm just wondering if anyone can tell me how you install the following perl modules on debiab :

```
install LWP
install DBI
install DBD::mysql
install GD
```

I tried with CPAN although when I ran

```
perl -MCPAN -e shell
install LWP
```

It was telling me I missing destination file operand.

Any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normally this is done without CPAN but with the Debian repositories. So

> apt-get install libwww-perl libdbi-perl libdbd-mysql-perl libgd-gd2-perl

Then you are done and even get security patches.

Comment: For me, only `libwww-perl` was necessary.